# Should functions that depend upon specific values be made unsafe?

Tags: rust, parameters, unsafe, requirements

I have a function that takes a `usize` equivalent to a pointer, and aligns it up to the next alignment point.

It doesn't require any unsafe as it's side effect free, but the alignment must be a power of two with this implementation. This means that if you use the function with bad parameters, you might get undefined behaviour later down the line. I can't check for this inside the function itself with `assert!` as it's supposed to be very fast.

```rust
/// Align the given address `addr` upwards to alignment `align`.
///
/// Unsafe as `align` must be a power of two.
unsafe fn align_next_unsafe(addr: usize, align: usize) -> usize {
    (addr + align - 1) & !(align - 1)
}
```

Currently, I've made this unsafe for the above reasons, but I'm not sure if that's best practice. Should I only define a function as unsafe if it has side effects? Or is this a valid time to require an unsafe block?

Comment: Given the context, `unsafe` seems the right semantics IMO, personally I'd provide a `align_next` returning `Result<usize, _>` as a safe variant; then benchmark and prove categorically if the validation overhead is too costly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying this is a fairly opinion-heavy answer, and represents a point of view, rather than "the truth".

Consider this code taken from the `Vec` docs:

```rust
let x = vec![1, 2, 4];
let x_ptr = x.as_ptr();

unsafe {
    for i in 0..x.len() {
        assert_eq!(*x_ptr.add(i), 1 << i);
    }
}
```

The function you're describing seems to have a similar safety profile to `Vec::as_ptr`. `Vec::as_ptr` is not `unsafe`, and does nothing particularly bad on its own; having an invalid `*const T` isn't bad until you dereference it. That's why dereferencing the raw pointer requires `unsafe`.

Similarly, I'd argue that `align_next` doesn't do anything particularly bad unless that value is then passed into some `unsafe` context. As with any question of `unsafe`, it's a tradeoff between safety/risk and ergonomics.

In `Vec::as_ptr`'s case, the risk is relatively low; the stdlib has lots of eyes on it, and is well "battle-tested". Moreover, it is a single function with a single implementation.

If your `align_next` was a function on a trait, I'd be much more tempted to make it unsafe, since someone in the future could implement it badly, and you might have other code whose safety relies on a correct implementation of `align_next`.

However, in your case, I'd say the pattern is similar to `Vec::as_ptr`, and you should make sure that any functions that consume this value are marked `unsafe` if they can cause UB.

I'd also second Martin Gallagher's point about creating a `Result` returning variant and benchmarking (you could also try an `Option<usize>`-returning API to make use of null-pointer optimizations).

Comment: “If your _align_next_ was a function on a trait, I'd be much more tempted to make it unsafe, since someone in the future could implement it badly” — When a bad implementation is a hazard, that means you should make the _trait_ `unsafe`, not the function. `unsafe fn` means “caller must obey some additional documented requirements to be sound”; `unsafe trait` means the _implementor_ must obey the requirements for the program to be sound.